# How to add and update Business rule in Oracle BPM application using java code in JDeveloper tool

Tags: java, oracle, rest, oracle12c, business-process-management

I have a requirement where we need to add Business rule inside the decision table and update the existing decision table Business rule.

Comment: Please provide Minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am new to Oracle BRE Application don't know what needs to show. my main question is it possible to add a Business Rule from our Custom Java Class into already Existing Decision Table.